How can I write a HotChocolate middleware that acts after UseFiltering?
I am building a GraphQL interface in an existing dotnet webapi using HotChocolate v13.
I want to write a middleware in a field that has UseFiltering(), which as far as I know is a middleware as well.
But when I put breakpoints in my middleware before and after calling await next(context); the filters don't seem to be applied yet.
Consider the following code
public class QueryType : ObjectType<Query>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<GraphQuery> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Authorize();

        descriptor
            .Field(x => x.GetProducts(default!, default!))
            .UseFiltering()
            .Use(next => async context =>
            {
                //Breakpoing here: context.Result is null
                await next(context);
                //Breakpoing here: context.Result has AppDbContext.Products (without filters)
            })
            .Type<ListType<ProductType>>();

        base.Configure(descriptor);
    }
}

public class Query
{
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([Service] AppDbContext dbContext, [ScopedService] ICurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        return dbContext.Products;
    }
}

If I send a query with filters to this field, none of the breakpoints show me a filtered IQueryable<Product> in context.Result
Is there a way in which I can write a middleware that at some point has the IQueryable<Product> with the filter sent by the client already applied?

What are you actually trying to do? When used with EF, GraphQL operators are converted to a LINQ query which in turn is translated to SQL by the DbContext, not GraphQL. Filtering is performed by the database, not the middleware. EF integration doesn't require (or use) such configuration either

In any case, the fact the DbContext only appears after next means your own middleware was registered before the EF integration middleware and so can't affect the LINQ query. If you want to apply eg a tenant filter, why not use EF's global query filters?

@PanagiotisKanavos I want to write a middleware that modifies the IQueryable after the filters are added to it, and before it gets translated into a SQL query.
What happens after await next(context) is not DbContext. What happens is that context.Result now has a value, but the value is just what is returned from the field.

And , why don't you use global query filters or interceptors for this? You're trying to modify the LINQ query, not the GraphQL  query. The before it's translated to SQL part is inside EF - the conversion happens when the application first tries to enumerate the LINQ query

@PanagiotisKanavos Because what I need to modify is not necessarily a filter. I may need to change joins or even the select

ORMs have relations, not JOINs. They deal with entities, not tables. If you want a different base query, why not modify GetProducts with extra Where and Select? In any case you can't modify EF query processing with unrelated middleware. What are you really trying to do? It seems this is an XY problem

To see filtered data you need to first understand the order of the middleware. HotChocolate's filtering middleware works by modifying the IQueryable and adding expressions to it. However, the actual query execution (which translates the IQueryable to a database query and executes it) happens later in the pipeline.
Below is the code with the logging you can check:
AppDbContext.cs:
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }


    }
}

GraphQL\Query.cs:
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Data;
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models;

namespace GraphQLMiddlewareExample.GraphQL
{
    public class Query
    {
         [UseFiltering]
        public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([Service] AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return dbContext.Products;
        }


    }
}

GraphQL\QueryType.cs:
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models;

namespace GraphQLMiddlewareExample.GraphQL
{
    public class QueryType : ObjectType<Query>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Query> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(x => x.GetProducts(default!))
                .Use(next => async context =>
                {
                    var logger = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<QueryType>>();
                    logger.LogInformation("Before next middleware is invoked");

                    await next(context);

                    logger.LogInformation("After next middleware is invoked");

                    if (context.Result is IQueryable<Product> queryable)
                    {
                        logger.LogInformation("context.Result is IQueryable<Product>");

                        var filteredProducts = queryable.ToList(); // Execute the query to get filtered results

                        logger.LogInformation("Filtered products count: {0}", filteredProducts.Count);

                        foreach (var product in filteredProducts)
                        {
                            logger.LogInformation("Product - Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Price: {2}", product.Id, product.Name, product.Price);
                        }

                        context.Result = filteredProducts; // You can inspect 'filteredProducts' here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.LogInformation("context.Result is not IQueryable<Product>");
                    }
                })
                .Type<ListType<ObjectType<Product>>>();

        }


    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Data;
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample.GraphQL;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using GraphQLMiddlewareExample;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ProductsDb"));

builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<QueryType>()
    .AddFiltering()
    .UseField<LoggingMiddleware>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddLogging();

var app = builder.Build();

// Seed the database
SeedDatabase(app);

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGraphQL();
});

app.Run();

static void SeedDatabase(WebApplication app)
{
    using var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();

    context.Products.AddRange(
        new GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models.Product { Name = "Product1", Price = 10 },
        new GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models.Product { Name = "Product2", Price = 20 },
        new GraphQLMiddlewareExample.Models.Product { Name = "Product3", Price = 30 }
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}



Yes, you are right. However, if you log the result of filteredProducts, you will see that the filter specified in your query (price > 25) is still not applied.

here you can see based on the query i have fired it shows the right filtered product: image

another example: image1 , image2
